# My app says that it has unfortunately stopped working(android app)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, toast, ratingbar

This is the code for the first screen and I have used all import statements for both the screens. I have a conditional statement which check if the editText Boxes or the ratingBar is empty or not.

```
public class BasicDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_details_screen);

        TextView textClass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textClass);
        TextView textSchool = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSchool);
        TextView textPhoto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPhoto);
        TextView textabtYear = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textabtYear);

        final EditText editClass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editClass);
        final EditText editSchool = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSchool);
        final EditText abtyear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.abtYear);

        //Button buttonPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPhoto);
        Button buttonBnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBnext);

        buttonBnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Performs action on click
                if ((editClass.getText().length() != 0) && (editSchool.getText().length() != 0) && (abtyear.getText().length() != 0)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BasicDetails.this, PortfolioDetails.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //opens the portfolio details class

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BasicDetails.this, "Please enter all the details!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is the code for the next screen. So basically there is an intent which takes you from one screen to the other but I get a error message on my emulator that"My app(or GoPort)has unfortunately stopped working"

```
public class PortfolioDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.porfolio_details_screen);

        TextView textAchievements = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAchievements);
        TextView textProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textProgress);
        TextView textFeedback = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textFeedback);

        final EditText editAchievements = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAchievements);
        final EditText editFeedback = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editFeedback);

        final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        Button buttonCnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCNext);

        buttonCnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Performs action on click

                if ((editAchievements.getText().length() != 0) && (editFeedback.getText().length() != 0)) {

                    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                                    boolean fromUser) {
                            // place intent for new activity

                            Intent intent = new Intent(PortfolioDetails.this, SlamDetails.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //opens the portfolio details class

                        }
                    });
                } else { 
                    Toast.makeText(PortfolioDetails.this, "Please enter all the details!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I get this in my log:
[image: The red text is what I feel is an error]

Comment: can you attach the error log you see in logcat

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: can you define what is your problem ??

Comment: @Ironman basically what happens is that I have a home screen.class where you enter your name and then click on a button to start. Once you click on that button, You go to the BasicDetails.class and when I input all the required details there, I click on the next button to go to the PortfolioDetails.class and thats when I encounter an error which says "GoPort has unfortunately stopped working"

Comment: @GodslaveAsad  I don't have any errors as such in the logcat but the apps stops working thats what I am trying to resolve. But I do see some text red in log but it doesn't seem to look like an error

Comment: It is showing error at **BasicDetails.java:43**. Which line is written on line 43 ?
Also its showing ActivityNotFoundException, so make sure the activity is registered in AndroidManifest.

Comment: @Somendra Meena ok so how do I do it..I am using a macbook (just for your info)

Comment: on line 43 I have startActivity(intent) is the error because I have duplicate variable (intent)in all the screens???

Comment: thank you @SomendraMeena I have done it!!

Comment: Go to your `app` folder and then in `manifests` open `AndroidManifest.xml` and then add activity within your `application` tag. Add your activity like this : 


    <application
        ...>
        <activity android:name=".BasicDetails">
            ...
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PortfolioDetails" />
        <activity android:name=".SlamDetails"></activity>
    </application>

Comment: Having duplicate _variable_ will not cause any problem if they are on different activities. If you have same variable name within a activity and if one is having scope in another part (where sec. variable is used), then it will give error. Otherwise you won't get any error cause of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: I actually forgot to add the activity to the intent]

Yeah I solved the issue....Basically there was no problem with the intent

Comment: also add `SlamDetails` in your Manifest file because you are using it in your `PortfolioDetails` Activity. Otherwise you will again go in that situation.